# Without using `protected`, how the subclass can effectively use the variables defined in base class

Tags: c++

Bjarne Stroustrup once said that he can address most of the tasks with ONLY private or public member variables and he seldom uses `protected` member variables in his design. I have heard similar arguments in other places. Here is an example,

```
class BaseClass
{
   ...
private:
   int m_iAge;
   double m_dSalary;
   string m_strName;
   bool m_bGender;
}

class SubClass : public BaseClass
{
   ...
}
```

Given the above class design, how the subclass `SubClass` can use the variables defined in `BaseClass`?

**Question1**> Why we should prefer to having `private` rather than `protected` variables? Is it the reason that the `BaseClass` can hide the implementation detail and make it easy for further improvement?

**Question2**> In order to let the `SubClass` access the variable defined in `BaseClass`, it seems to me that we have to define public access(get/set). However, getter/setter are evil! So the second choice is to define protected access(get/set). Any better idea?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure that getters and setters are _evil_, though it is very nice to use the property syntax that you get in many languages (though not in Java and C++).

Comment: Holub, Allen. Why getter and setter methods are evil. JavaWorld.com, September 2003. http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2003/jw-0905-toolbox.html

Comment: In java, getter/setters are indeed evil, but in c++, judicious use of helper classes with `operator T const& () const` and `operator = (T const&)` / `operator = (T &&)` and `(T &)` constructors make it far more elegant. This is especially useful when dealing with POD types which require a certain endianness when `memcpy`ing in and out.

Comment: For example: http://pastebin.com/wZDQdTN3

Answer (score 2):

Bjarne's point is that generally the derived class *shouldn't* access the variables of the base class -- doing so frequently leads to maintenance problems. And no, changing it to use `get`/`set` (accessor/mutator) functions isn't an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself - why would the derived class ever change the value of `m_bGender`? Or `m_iAge`? Doesn't the base class already handle these values correctly?

See, there is generally no need to *have* direct access to the internals of the base class. So we make them private, and use the class' public interface.

In some very rare cases, there might also be one or two protected functions, if derived classes need some special interface. But that is unusual. If derived classes have different behaviour, we more often use virtual functions for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the rationale for this claim is that in many situations, subclassing doesn't often change the behavior of the existing (inherited fields), but rather one adds fields and adds new methods that manipulate the new fields.

If you are looking for a way to manipulate inherited members w/o protected, you can, in the base class, make the derived class a friend.  You would have to know it ahead of time, though.

Comment: friends don't let friends use `friend`

Comment: @JasonS: Nonsense! Granted, this doesn't sound like a good time to use `friend` (at least to me), but that hardly means there is no such thing. Just for one obvious example, most stream extractors (std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &, whatever &);` should be friends of the `whatever` class.

Comment: I should have mentioned I'm not a fan of `friend` either; I was throwing it out as an alternative.  I'll stand by the first part of the answer though: *most of the time* inheritance doesn't require that you change the behavior of the superclass related to the inherited fields, but rather to the _new_ fields.  If the subclass for some reason does need to manipulate the inherited structure then sure you can make the base class members `protected` or make the base class's interface flexible enough that you can effect them through methods, not necessarily `get` and `set`.

Answer (score 0):

The only main reason to use private over protected members is if they indeed are not required in child implementations. That's *why* we have protected members, because there are cases where the child class does need direct access to members of a parent class. I think Stroustrup is referring to a design whereby there is little need to access parent members in the first place, and child classes simply build upon the functionality of their parent rather than modify the functionality of their parent.

> However, getter/setter are evil!

Why so? Getters and setters are an important part of OOP from my experience. There are good reasons to make an interface with a class, rather than access its variables directly.